# r programming --- conditional assignment producing unexpected results

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which I need to create a new variable based on values of two other variables. The results are not according to my expectation. Here is what I have:

```
d <- data.frame(
     customer = rep(c("a","b"),3),
     prod1 = c("tea", "gum", "candy", "tea","snack", "bar"),
     prod2 = c(NA, NA, "juice", NA,NA,"cocoa")

)

d <- d[order(d$customer),]

> d
  customer prod1 prod2
1        a   tea  <NA>
3        a candy juice
5        a snack  <NA>
2        b   gum  <NA>
4        b   tea  <NA>
6        b   bar cocoa
```

I want to create another variable that takes values of prod2 only when !is.na(prod2) is true, else take values of prod1.  I tried following two ways and created two different variables to compare results:

```
ifelse(!is.na(d$prod2),
   d$products1 <- d$prod2, d$products1 <- d$prod1)

d$products2[is.na(d$prod2)]  <- d$prod1[is.na(d$prod2)]
d$products2[!is.na(d$prod2)] <- d$prod2[!is.na(d$prod2)]
```

I get :

```
> d
  customer prod1 prod2 products1 products2  i.wanted
1        a   tea  <NA>       tea         5     tea  
3        a candy juice     candy         2     juice
5        a snack  <NA>     snack         4     snack
2        b   gum  <NA>       gum         3     gum
4        b   tea  <NA>       tea         5     tea
6        b   bar cocoa       bar         1     cocoa
```

What I wanted is in column i.wanted but thats not what i am getting.  The ifelse condition creates products1 by simply taking values from prod1 and nothing from prod2.  The second approach returns a vector of numbers.

Any help appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are passing a vector of TRUE/FALSE values to the ifelse function. R doesen't like it if you do conditional branching with a variable of several logical values - because which one is the one it should consider? Often it will just assume the first TRUE/FALSE value in the vector and give you a warning. Anyway, here's one way you can do it with an apply function:

```
d$i.wanted <- apply(d, 1, function(x){
  if(!is.na(x[3])){
    return(x[3])
  } else {
    return(x[2])
  }
})
```

Here I loop over d, row by row, and check if the third variable i.e. the value in column prod2 is not na, if so it is returned. If it is NA, then the second variable i.e. the value from prod1 is returned.

Furthermore, your second solution is actually almost right, you're reasoning on the indexing is spot on, the reason it is probably giving you issues is that it is attempting to combine two different factor variables, which store categorical variables by storing each unique value as a "Level":

```
> d$prod1
[1] tea   candy snack gum   tea   bar  
Levels: bar candy gum snack tea
> d$prod2
[1] <NA>  juice <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  cocoa
Levels: cocoa juice
```

The the vector indexes those levels i.e. d$prod1 is 5, 2, 4, 3... and so on. Because bar is the 5th level, candy is the 2nd level, and so on.
Then you can start to see why this might be problematic in prod 1, there are 5 levels 1:5, and in prod2, there are two levels 1:2. in prod1 any "bar" is stored as 1, but in prod2 any cocoa is also stored as a 1. If you modiufy the code you've written to treat the columns as vectors of character strings instead of factors, then your two lines will work:

```
d$products2[is.na(d$prod2)]  <- as.character(d$prod1)[which(is.na(d$prod2))]
d$products2[!is.na(d$prod2)] <- as.character(d$prod2)[which(!is.na(d$prod2))]
```

Hope that helps!
B.

Comment: Thanks Ward!  Your solution works.  I did play with the ifelse condition. Looks like one needs an assignment.  Pl see in "Answer Your Question"

Answer (score 0):

Ward thanks for pointing out to using character vector instead of the default factor.  Your solution to bracketed conditional worked.  However, I tried ifelse in different ways and here is what I found:

following DID NOT work as I wanted :

```
ifelse(!is.na(d$prod2),
       d$products1 <- as.character(d$prod2), 
       d$products1 <- as.character(d$prod1))
```

here are two different conditionals producing the desired results:

```
d$products2 <- ifelse(!is.na(d$prod2),
               d$products2 <- as.character(d$prod2), 
               d$products2 <- as.character(d$prod1)) 

d$products3 <- ifelse(!is.na(d$prod2),
               as.character(d$prod2), 
               as.character(d$prod1))
```

from the results above, I see that I needed an assignment before the ifelse condition was required along with as.character. d$products1 and d$products2 are created exactly the same way except that d$products2 has an assignment operator before the ifelse condition.

here are the results (products2, 3, and 4 are all good):

```
> d
  customer prod1 prod2 products1 products2 products3 products4
1        a   tea  <NA>       tea       tea       tea       tea
3        a candy juice     candy     juice     juice     juice
5        a snack  <NA>     snack     snack     snack     snack
2        b   gum  <NA>       gum       gum       gum       gum
4        b   tea  <NA>       tea       tea       tea       tea
6        b   bar cocoa       bar     cocoa     cocoa     cocoa
```

Comment: dont use an assignment within the ifelse.